# Using -mod flag in go CLI

Tags: go

I was reading through godoc on how I can keep my dependencies up to date: https://golang.org/ref/mod#build-commands

It says that `-mod=mod` flag can be used to automatically update the go.mod file. But I am not able to use it.

This is the command that I tried:

```
% go get -mod=mod ./..                                 
flag provided but not defined: -mod
usage: go get [-d] [-t] [-u] [-v] [-insecure] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help get' for details.
```

I am obviously missing something because I can't seem to get the flag to work.

Comment: Could you please tell us which `go` version you are using?

Comment: @shmsr I am using 1.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit: It's a documentation error

After some experiments, it looks that only quite old versions of Go understand `go get -mod=`, in particular version 1.11. So the documentation is outdated and you could report it.

Officially recommended on Go version 1.14 or newer: to automatically update an existing `go.mod` file and to download dependencies, instead of doing `go get -mod=mod .`, simply run:

```sh
go get -d .
```

For the sake of the example being complete, you could now actually build everything and put binaries into `$GOBIN` (or `$GOPATH/bin`) with:

```sh
go install
```

If it still doesn't work, a couple of things to check:

### Update `go` to the latest version

The online documentation that you are reading is always about the latest official version, while you might be using an older version. Check your version:

```sh
go version
```

With the current pace of Go development, most people are trying to update as soon as they can. Follow https://golang.org/doc/install

### Docs for the older version

Apparently, there is no easy way to read older documentation online. Instead, I use `godoc` tool to do it locally:

```sh
go get -v  golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
godoc -http=127.0.0.1:6060
```

Leave the above command **running**, then in your browser go to http://127.0.0.1:6060/cmd/go/

This way I've checked for example what the old docs said about `-mod` flag.

Comment: She's talking about updating the dependencies but your answer is nowhere near.

Comment: @shmsr OP wants to use the new `-mod` as documented and receives an error `flag provided but not defined: -mod`. I assume they want to use `-mod` and don't question the reason. There is not enough data to simply tell they shouldn't. The advice how to deal with exactly that seems to me exactly on topic for OP but, more importantly, also for anyone arriving here via a search engine.

Comment: @shmsr Updated for go1.16, it looks like a documentation error.

Comment: Yeah, raised the issue yesterday. Here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/44760

Comment: @kubanczyk thanks for you detailed answer. I observed that with go get -d, it upgrades the dependencies to the latest version and not the latest stable version. Is there any way to upgrade only for the stable version? Thanks.

Comment: @SaloniKogta Hmm I don't really understand what you mean by "stable" here. Maybe there's already a Q&A here about that? Or you can create one?

Comment: You can go `go mod tidy` and then no updating takes place at all, only the `go.mod` cleanup.